# R - How to smooth a conversion of weekly sales into daily sales?

Tags: r, smoothing

I have weekly sales figures, and would like to convert them into daily sales figures, making a simple hypothesis that there are 7 days with equal sales "power".

Let's imagine that I have:

```
Week, Sales
1,11
2,15
3,9
```

Now I can easily convert this into daily figures with "flat" weekly patterns:

```
Week,Day,Sales
1,1,11/7
1,2,11/7
1,3,11/7
1,4,11/7
1,5,11/7
1,6,11/7
1,7,11/7
2,1,15/7
2,2,15/7
2,3,15/7
2,4,15/7
etc
```

But the main improvement I am looking for is to have a linear trend inside the week, so that I smooth the jump from week 1 to week 2 (from 11 to 15).
Is there an R function that can do this work for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some solution with the R zoo package:

```
> z <- zoo(c(NA, NA, NA, 11, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, 9, NA, NA, NA), c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21))
> z
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 
NA NA NA 11 NA NA NA NA NA NA 15 NA NA NA NA NA NA  9 NA NA NA 
> na.approx(z) 
        4         5         6         7         8         9        10        11        12        13        14        15 
11.000000 11.571429 12.142857 12.714286 13.285714 13.857143 14.428571 15.000000 14.142857 13.285714 12.428571 11.571429 
       16        17        18 
10.714286  9.857143  9.000000
```

Comment: or `x=c(11,15,9);  z=zoo(c(rbind(NA,NA,NA,x,NA,NA,NA)))` etc. But you'll want to divide `x` by 7 first.